# Addressable LED Strip with Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, node.js, raspberry-pi, led, gpio

I have been researching this for a while and haven't found anything conclusive.

I want to use an addressable LED with my Raspberry pi, probably with node.js (npm gpio) or python. I don't know much about circuits but I have a feeling raspberry pi doesn't have digital write ability.

The strip has 4 inputs (5v, SDI, CKI, GND)
I am using this: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B008F05N54/ref=oh_details_o01_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008F05N54)

Here is what I have for a single LED that works but not for the strip:

```
var gpio = require("gpio");
var gpio22, gpio4, intervalTimer;

// Flashing lights if LED connected to GPIO22
gpio22 = gpio.export(22, {
   ready: function() {
      inervalTimer = setInterval(function() {
         gpio22.set();
         setTimeout(function() { gpio22.reset(); }, 500);
      }, 1000);
   }
});

// Lets assume a different LED is hooked up to pin 4, the following code 
// will make that LED blink inversely with LED from pin 22 
gpio4 = gpio.export(4, {
   ready: function() {
      // bind to gpio22's change event
      gpio22.on("change", function(val) {
         gpio4.set(1 - val); // set gpio4 to the opposite value
      });
   }
});

// reset the headers and unexport after 10 seconds
setTimeout(function() {
   clearInterval(intervalTimer);          // stops the voltage cycling
   gpio22.removeAllListeners('change');   // unbinds change event
   gpio22.reset();                        // sets header to low
   gpio22.unexport();                     // unexport the header

   gpio4.reset();
   gpio4.unexport(function() {
      // unexport takes a callback which gets fired as soon as unexporting is done
      process.exit(); // exits your node program
   });
}, 10000)
```

What I want to do is get this to work with my addressable led strip:

Does anyone know if I can do this with a digital write to work with my addressable LED? Am i approaching this wrong?

Thanks!! I have stumped on this.

Comment: I have a feeling, someone will close this thread. Make your question more generic - i.e without raspberry pi.

Comment: This looks like it uses the same chipset as[this](http://www.adafruit.com/products/738). Maybe you can try to look at [this library](https://github.com/RussTheAerialist/node-spi).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this tutorial. Although I don't fully understand the way the strips work, I have managed to get mine to work in a sort of random way with my Pi using this code, but my strip is not made by the same manufacturer. I have found it much easier to use my Arduino to program the strip. Also there are some great tutorials in Make magazine on using Adafruit's LED strips and panels.

https://learn.adafruit.com/light-painting-with-raspberry-pi/overview

Cheers

Steve